# Python Subprocess to delete reg key on Windows

Tags: python, windows, escaping, registry, subprocess

My code doesn't work as expected :

```
import subprocess

key = 'reg delete HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2637495828-1099793317-3825703309-1000\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-D955BE4EEF1D} /f'
subprocess.call(key, shell=True)
```

Running Windows 10 64b, tried with subprocess.Popen aswell.

My first thought is I have to escape \ somehow, but I'm not sure if that's what I need, nor how to do it.
I also tried to make it work with a list of args `key = ['reg', 'delete', 'HKEY...'])`, which gave the same result

Result from python script

```
C:\test.py
Error : Couldn't find the key or registry value
```

Result from the command from the Windows prompt

```
C:\reg delete HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2637495828-1099793317-3825703309-1000\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-D955BE4EEF1D} /f
Operation Suceeded
```

N.B. I exported the key so I can add it again after every successful try.

N.B. Windows return messages were translated, and may not be accurate.

Comment: Have you tried supplying it as a list of arguments? i.e. `key = ['reg', 'delete', 'HKEY...']`

Comment: What about if you do `shell=False`?

Comment: If you simply launch _python_ what's the 1st line that it displays?

Comment: Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

wasn't expecting the 32 bits thing tbh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought so (the ***32bit*** part). You're running into a problem generated by [[MS>Docs]: Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WinProg64/shared-registry-keys).

In other words (on *64bit* *Win*), for some registry keys (this one included), there are 2 separate locations:

- One for *64bit* (default (and old) one)
- One for *32bit* (brand new)

By default a *64bit* app automatically uses the *64bit* registry location; same thing for *32bit8 (of course that can be programmatically modified - at least for *64bit* apps).

So, in order for *32bit* apps that have some registry keys hardcoded, to still work on *64bit* *Win* (remember the key hardcoded in the *32bit* app is now *64bit*, and it's *invisible* to the app, while the ***real*** *32bit* is someplace else), *MS* came up with this approach. Same approach applies to paths on the filesystem (***System32*** *vs* ***SysWOW64*** under *C:\Windows*).

Now why does it work from *cmdline*? Being a *64bit* *OS*, the default *cmd* is *64bit* (which launches the *64bit* *reg.exe*), so it finds the key. Yes, you have 2 *cmd*s (one under each of the above folders), actually (almost) all the *Win* executables (and *.dll*s) are "duplicated".

To test, start *cmd.exe* from *C:\Windows\SysWOW64*, and run the *reg* command and it will fail.

Finally, to get past this, associate *.py* files (I noticed that you ran it directly) with a *64bit* *Python* version (you might have to download and install it).

Comment: I won't try right now to apply your advice but the test with SysWOW64 gives me the result you predicted, 

I'll try to install python (64b) in a separate directory so my existing scripts (using weird dependencies) will continue to work.

Thanks !

Comment: Tried it, didn't mess with my other scripts, worked like a charm !

Comment: I just have another idea, you could delete the key "manually" from _Python_ using the [_winreg](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) module (it comes as part of newer _Python_ versions), you can try deleting it from both 64 and 32 bit locations, so you wouldn't care what kind of _Python_ is running the script, but that's not doable in 2 lines of code :).

Comment: FYI, the WOW64 system allows using "SysNative" to virtually refer to the real System32 directory. For example: `sysnative = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'SysNative');` `reg = os.path.join(sysnative, 'reg.exe');` `subprocess.call('"%s" query HKLM' % reg)`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that!