# Why Get-ChildItem (or ls, or dir) returns different results being executed on x86 and x64 powershell console

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, 64-bit

I started Powershell Console for x86 on my Windows Server machine and executed:

```
get-childitem C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\*s
```

and I get the following list:

> CimCmdlets,DirectAccessClientComponents,Kds,Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics,NetQos,NetworkConnectivityStatus,PSDiagnostics,ScheduledTasks,TLS

Then I started x64 console and executed the same command, and get much wider list of DIRs:

> **BestPractices**,CimCmdlets,DirectAccessClientComponents,**FailoverClusters**,Kds,Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics,NetQos,NetworkConnectivityStatus,**NFS**,PSDiagnostics,ScheduledTasks,**SmbWitness**,TLS

I checked the hardlinks for the FailoverClusters module file (which I'm actually tried to import):

```
PS C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules> fsutil hardlink list C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\FailoverClusters\failoverclusters.psd1
```

and I get the following result:

> \Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\FailoverClusters\FailoverClusters.psd1
>   \Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-f..rcluster-powershell_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17112_none_8555e001e29b71bc\FailoverClusters.psd1

(Note: looks like directory itself has no links, fsutil returns only one entry - same as dirname)

So the question is: why does `Get-ChildItem` work differently on x86 vs x64 powershell hosts? How does this actually work?

Yes, I understand that FailoverClusters module doesn't work on x86 architecture, but still... I broke my head trying to figure out where is the mistake (accidentally compiled my C# host for x86 architecture), because it always returns me something like "module not found" or "file not found"....

Comment: I would recommend starting with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249.aspx).

Comment: Check the 3rd paragraph of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236009/python-subprocess-to-delete-reg-key-on-windows/32237671#32237671. A more elaborate answer can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed this. I was so sure in such simple things as "dir" (probably from FAT32 times, when it was enough to put 0x0 in foder name to make it inaccessible...) that it was hard to believe things gets much more complicated...

Answer (score 3):

[From my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332305/3905079):

On a 32 bit Windows OS, the system folder is `C:\Windows\System32`. 
On a 64 bit Windows OS, the 64 bit system folder is also `C:\Windows\System32`. But the system folder for 32 bit processes on a 64 bit Windows installation is in fact `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

For compatibility, a 32 bit process on a 64 bit OS will have any calls to `C:\Windows\System32` **transparently redirected** to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, unbeknownst to the process.

To enable a 32 bit process to reference the *real* `System32` on a 64 bit OS, you can you use `C:\Windows\SysNative`.

Since PowerShell has a 32 bit and a 64 bit version, and it lives inside the system folders, you need to use the above rules to reference the correct executable depending on whether you're calling it from a 64 or 32 bit process.

The typical scenario (you want to call the version of the same bitness) is easiest (just call `powershell.exe` or reference it via `System32`), but it gets hairy if you want to reference the *other* version.

---

#### Getting Modules

I'll further add that if you want to see what modules are available, you should be calling [`Get-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849700.aspx) instead of looking in the directories.

#### Using 64bit-only modules in 32bit code

If you need the functionality of a module that's only available from 64 bit code, in 32 bit code, you can use PowerShell Remoting to accomplish this.

You can remote into a 64 bit machine (even the current machine), execute the code you need, get the results back in the 32 bit process.

You can also use implicit remoting to use the commands remotely as though they're available locally:

Example (from 32 bit powershell):

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName . # connecting to the local computer
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Import-Module NFS }
Import-PSSessin -Session $session -Module NFS

# Call NFS cmdlets
# more program stuff

Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Obviously, I used Import/Get-Module functions, but it was hard to match "file not found" error with "you are using x86 compiled host C# application" as an actual reason of this problem.

Comment: @PavelMaltsev added some more to answer about how you might be able to use 64 bit modules from 32 bit powershell.